# How to "isolate" two local postgres databases from each other when migrating one using flask-migrate

Tags: postgresql, flask-migrate

I have two projects (A and B) that are using Postgres databases. They share the same host ("localhost") and username, but the database names are different ("databaseA" and "databaseB"). The two projects are in different directories (sibling directories, next to each other). I have this environment variable set: `DATABASE_URL=postgresql://localhost`

I am working on setting up Flask-Migrate for databaseB and I'm working in the directory for the databaseB project. When I issued the `flask db init` command, everything looked correct (i.e. it created the migrations and versions directories and all the scripts etc. in the correct location under my project B directory.

However, when I issued the `flask db migrate -m "Initial migration"` command, the output shows many operation related to databaseA as well as the desired operations for databaseB.

What do I need to do to limit the scope of the `flask db migrate -m "Initial migration"` to project B and databaseB?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to modify the DATABASE_URL environment variable to specify the target database (databaseB) as follows:

`DATABASE_URL=postgresql://localhost/databaseB`